# Chrome 50 Change in implicit table-cell height behaviour

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, chromium

See [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zc21pg9q/1/).

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        Hello World
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

html, body {
  height:100%;
  background-color:steelblue;
  margin:0;
}

table {
  height:100%;
  border:1px;
}

td {
  border:1px;
}

tr {
  background-color: green;
}

div {
  background-color:salmon;
  height:100%;
}
```

Prior to Chrome 50, a table with height 100% would also implicitly apply height 100% to it's table cells.

This has been a [longstanding bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10212) in Firefox and IE versions < 11. Chrome and Safari have always passed the implicit percentage height onto the cells.

What is the correct behaviour according to the specifications? Has this been introduced by design?

Edit:
[Chromium Bug Report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=603835&can=2&start=100&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=)

Comment: Shouldn't this be a question for the Chrome people? Are they known to hang out on SO?

Comment: Submitted as a Chromium issue also. As this is having a major impact I was hoping for insight from a more responsive community.

Comment: It is likely seen as off topic here.

Comment: Hmmm...the specs [**CSS2.1**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html) and [**CSS2.2**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/tables.html#table-layout) -  a quick glance would seem to indicate that *" A 'height' value of 'auto' for a 'table-row' means the row height used for layout is MIN."* Deeper reading might indicate that Chrome has *corrected* to the right action...this could take some time.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be the same question as [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=583670&q=label%3ACr-Blink-Layout-Table&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) Chromium issue, which was closed over 2 months ago.
According to the comments there, the new behavior in Chrome 50 is "more spec compliant".

So, to answer your question, it would appear this *is* intentional, and is considered (at least by the Chromium developers) to be the correct behavior according to the specifications.

The solution, naturally, is to just explicitly set the cell's height to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer works (to explicity set the cells height to 100%)
If you want all cells to follow that patterns, you can simply use

```
<style>
   td{
     height:100%;
   }
</style>
```

Alternatively, you could try:

```
<style>
   td{
     height:inherit;
   }
</style>
```

I believe either should work.